# Howto run google assistand bitcoinInfo example webhook index.js

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to run the google assistant example webhook nodejs application(index.js) on my own server, but don't know what is the webhosting setup for this..
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-action-on-google-with-webhook/#2

What is the environment to run this app on my server? Since it's not running as a listening server, I can't use nginx, node_cgi is not mature with apache, how am I supposed to run this sample?

Comment: I had the same question when I found that virtually all of the samples have been updated to use Cloud Functions. No matter how good an option that is, IMO it is less than ideal for testing and development. I put a line like this

if ( module === require.main )
{
 expressApp.set('port', port);
 expressApp.listen(port);
}

in the "main" module intended to be started by Node for testing and require() it for Cloud Functions. If that's something you want to do and it is not obvious how to do it, post another question on sharing with Cloud Functions.

Comment: Good point! I'll fix it :) In the git repo we are now (thanks to Prisoner) supporting both cloud functions and firebase function.

Btw, I have created this example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aog-template-1 in order to make it easier for developers to test (quickly/easily) their webhook logic.

Comment: ...and thanks to you I also updated this bitcoin info tutorial: https://medium.com/@greenido/create-a-google-assistant-app-that-use-your-server-fac49c3513b1

Comment: Your glitch example is great, works like a charm , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help to @Prisoner and @Ido Green link works even better! The minimum to run the sample I did the following:

Create a new nodejs project with mainfile main.js, install express and actions-on-google

```
mkdir googleActionServer
cd googleActionServer  
npm init  
npm install --save actions-on-google  
npm install --save express`
```

Copy the index.js from google and put this into main.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bitcoinInfo = require("./index");
const app = express();
app.use( express.json() );

app.post('/', (req, res) => bitcoinInfo.bitcoinInfo( req, res ));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('App listening on port 3000!'));
```

Start the application by running:

```
node ./main.js
```

To test with DialogFlow, download and install ngrok to /usr/local/bin for ex and then run:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

Ngrok will give you an url that is accesible from outside and forward the requests to the nodejs app. It will also create a https for you, so copy paste the https address into DialogFlow webhook address and you are set to go

Answer (score 1):

Excellent point, and you should be sure to file a bug request on the page to indicate it is unclear.

The code, as presented, is meant to run using [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http).

This doesn't mean you can't run it on your own server - just that you need to know how to run a Node.js server outside of your Apache or Nginx environment. I've seen a number of configurations, but typically you'll have the Node.js server application running and listening to a local port and have a proxy between your externally facing web server at a particular path and this port.

But even that isn't sufficient in this case - the code itself doesn't listen on a port - it expects to be handed a `request` and `response` object in the form that Express.js with a JSON middleware can handle. To do that, you'll need to have installed the Express.js library and then start listening with code such as:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use( express.json() );

app.get('/', (req, res) => exports.bitcoinInfo( req, res ));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('App listening on port 3000!'));
```